# JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

Guys can you help me a little bit, Im getting this error:

```
"JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang cannot be converted to JSONObject"
```

When I'm parsing the data here is my code:

```
    public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser() {

    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

Here is the code where I'm instantiating the Parser:

```
private void fillSpinnerCabTypes() {        
    List<String> cabTypesSpinner = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject cabTypesObject = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(urlTypeCabs);
    try{
        TypesArray = cabTypesObject.getJSONArray(TAG_TYPES);

        for(int i = 0; i < TypesArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = TypesArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            cabTypesSpinner.add(name);
        }
    }catch(Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cabTypesSpinner);

     final Spinner spnCabTypes = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnTypeOfCab);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spnCabTypes.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I'm really stuck with this. I'm populating the spinner from a database in a backend on Django in the server.

This is my JSON data

```
{"Types": [{"name": "Normal"}, {"name": "Discapacitados"}, {"name": "Buseta"}]}
```

Comment: Show your logcat. And just let me know are you getting the json value form your php script? If yes just show me the format of your json.

Comment: post your log and json data.

Comment: please post your json.. without seeing the json format.. we cant help you

Comment: This error generally occurs when ur json data isn't in format, please check this [link](http://json.parser.online.fr/) copy paste ur json data and see if it is in json format

Comment: Please use `EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity())` instead of your hand-written code that ignores the encoding sent by the server, doesn't close on exception and converts line endings to `\n`. Also, don't use static variables when a local variable works just as well for `ìs`, `jObj`, `json`.

Answer (score 6):

This issue comes from the server.
The URL you're requesting, send you back data but not in the JSON format.
The Exception you get is telling you that the String the server send you back starts with:

```
<!DOCTYPE
```

This can be:

1. A simple webpage (instead of raw JSON). It correspond to the first XML tag of a web page ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp))
2. An error page generated by the server, and printed in HTML

To debug this further, simply print the content of your `json` variable in the logcat:

```
Log.d("Debug", json.toString());
jObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Comment: hi simon I am facing a problem to something similar to the above can you help if i posted a question?

Comment: @Moudiz sure, but if this doesn't corresponds to this issue, you'll have to create another issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply , my problem is similar to this. I want to connect to the server , but I am getting the same error above , I am not sure where is wrong. if i post a question can you look at it and see if you can help me ?

Comment: allright ill add everything to be clear to you. but i need a bit time , when I post the question ill notify to you here .. thank you

Comment: hi man can you check my question ?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102455/exception-connection-to-my-ip-refused-how-to-check-the-connection-is-correct

Answer (score 0):

This problem came in my code also.and solution was different.It occured due to spelling mistake of webservice.

Solution 1:

for example  real the url is

http://example.com/directory/file.php

and i had used

http://example.com/directory/file1.php

Solution 2:
use loopj library .it exactly gives you the explained error.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(str , localRequestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                super.onFinish();
                Log.i("onFinish","onFinish");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

                Log.i("onSuccess","onSuccess");



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.i("onFailure","onFailure");


            }

        });
```